# My code doesn't work on Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

since Win-7 drag and drop implementation has changed, to make it work I need to enable some stuff using [ChangeWindowMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There is a problem. `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` is valid since Vista, however I need solution for XP as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should try call it dynamically, for that you need [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

Sample usage

```
if (/*IsVista()*/)
{
    typedef BOOL (WINAPI *ChangeMessageFilter)(UINT message, DWORD dwFlag);
    #define MSGFLT_ADD 1
    #define MSGFLT_REMOVE 2
    BOOL res = FALSE;
    HMODULE user32 = LoadLibrary(L"User32.dll");
    if (user32 != NULL)
    {
        ChangeMessageFilter filter = (ChangeMessageFilter)::GetProcAddress(user32, "ChangeWindowMessageFilter");
        if (filter != NULL)
        {
            res = filter(/*your value*/, MSGFLT_ADD);
        }
        ::FreeLibrary(user32);
    }
}
```

---

Another thing, you should better use [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as it is enables messages receiving for only one window, not all project.

Comment: [`ChangeWindowMessageFilter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675.aspx) (Vista+) applies the change to the entire process as a wide.  [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202.aspx) (Win7+) applies the change to a specific window instead.